# Access to User details via QuickBooks API

Tags: quickbooks

When using the Xero API I can get details of all users associated with an organisation via the Users endpoint:
https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/users

Is it possible to access the same information via the QuickBooks API? For example, when I connect to a Company, can I get the details of all users of that Company?

Answer (score 1):

If the person comes in via OpenID SSO, you'll get their user details as part of the OpenID identity information:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/00_quickbooks_online/2_build/10_authentication_and_authorization/50_identity/10_openid_2.0

And you can get some information via the `CompanyInfo` supporting resource:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/companyinfo

And there's probably a good amount of overlap between the users and the `Employee` data:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/employee

But no, there's no API endpoint to get a list of all users within the company.